# Cases tactic in Lean does not create hypothesis

Tags: proof, lean

When using the `cases`-tactic on an inductive data type, lean produces multiple cases, but does not create a hypothesis stating the assumption of the current case. For example:

```
inductive color | blue | red

theorem exmpl (c : color) : true :=
begin
    cases c,
end
```

results in the following tactic state

```
case color.blue
⊢ true
case color.red
⊢ true
```

but does not create a separate hypothesis (like `c = color.red`) to work with. How would you get such a hypothesis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `cases h : c` to get a new hypothesis `h` for each case. For more detail, see the [documentation](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactics.html#cases).

In the example, this would be

```
theorem exmpl (c : color) : true :=
begin
  cases h : c,
end
```

resulting in

```
case color.blue
c: color
h: c = color.blue
⊢ true
case color.red
c: color
h: c = color.red
⊢ true
```